# How to open the file where you send the data to with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm completely new to ajax so I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.
I'm trying to pass an Javascript array to a PHP file. And if succesfully open the PHP file and display the array. The error I'm getting after opening the file is:

```
undefined $productList
```

Meanwhile if I inspect and look into the network tab the ajax is sent successfully and the response is also fine (I get to see the contents of the array), but when I try to open the file it throws me errors. So my question is how do I open a file where I send my data to with ajax?

Array:

```
array(6) { ["name"]=> string(28) "Inuyasha by rumiko takahashi" ["image"]=> string(35) "https://via.placeholder.com/195x280" ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["count"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(2) "12" ["basePrice"]=> string(2) "12" }
```

The ajax:

```
function passArray(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "assets/js/test.php",
        data: {productsInCart:productsInCart},
        error: function(){
          alert('something went wrong..');
        }
    });
    //window.open("assets/js/test.php", "_self"); //how to open the file where the data is sent?
}
```

The PHP code:

```
if($_POST){
    $productlist = $_POST;
}else{
    $productlist = "";
    echo "doesnt work ";
    
    die();
}
//var_dump($productlist);


foreach($productlist as $number){
    foreach ($number as $cat => $prop) {
        echo $cat;
        echo $prop;
    }
}

$html .= "</table>";
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  You're making *two separate requests* to `test.php`.  The second request is just a GET with no data/parameters.  If the goal is to redirect the user to the `test.php` page then why are you also using AJAX?  What's the intended functionality here?

Comment: @David So I made a shopping cart function in Javascript. Now I'm trying to pass the products (the array) to the PHP file after the customer clicked on the checkout button as well to redirect the customer to the PHP file and display the products. I'm assuming I'm not doing it properly?

Comment: Well, it makes little sense to make two requests to the same page.  You can abandon AJAX entirely and just do a normal form post to the intended page.  Or you can separate the *page* from the AJAX data handling, where you might make an AJAX request to a PHP file which specifically just handles the data and persists it to a database, then redirect the user to a page which reads data from that database.  Of course, don't redirect the user until *after* the AJAX operation completes (so in the `success` function here).

Comment: Variables don't persist between requests. So your second request (from the window.open command) starts your PHP script all over again, except this time you didn't send it any data, and it knows nothing about the data you sent last time (during the ajax request). Web applications are inherently _stateless_, i.e. they have no memory by default. If, in a second request, you want to see the same data you sent previously, then you have to program your script to save the data somewhere the first time, and then read it from there the second time.

Comment: But I agree it would probably make more sense not to use AJAX, and just to post a form back to the second script. _Or_ you stick with AJAX, but don't then redirect - just have it store the data in your "cart" (e.g. database or session), and when the ajax request finished, you can just use JS to update the current page (for example with a message to say the data was successfully added, and/or to show the list of added items somewhere else in the page). After all the whole reason AJAX exists is to prevent the need to be always refreshing or redirecting, and to provide a smoother user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two different requests to the same  URL.

- With `$.ajax` you are making a POST request.
- With `window.open` you are making a GET request.

The PHP program will run *independently* for each request. The data you are posting in the first request will not be available in the second request.

If you want to display a page you get as the result of POSTing some data then use:

```
<form action="..." method="post" target="_self">
```

Don't use Ajax (which is for making an HTTP request **without leaving the current page** — generally you would take the data in the response to the Ajax request and use DOM manipulation to add it to the current page).